# How to read and edit excel files simultaneously (using SharePoint)?

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, simultaneous

For a project a client asked me to make a program that can manipulate multiple Excel files into one single excel output file, with the ability for other employees to still work on the output file simultaneously.

Having done some research I have found it seems possible using SharePoint. I've done similar projects before but only on a local level, never multi-user nor have I ever developed something in SharePoint. I was wondering is it is indeed possible and how does it need to be set up, which libraries should I use etc.

About the libraries, I really detest using the COM Interop library because of the annoying and hard to solve memory issues.